# data access problem in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have the following class-files:

```
class RowData {
...
  ArrayList<String> valueMap;
...
}

class Bean {
...
  public List<RowData> getData() {
  ...
  }
}
```

jsf code snippet:

```
...
<h:form>
  <rich:dataTable id="overviewTable" value="#{bean.getData()}" var="row">

    <c:forEach items="#{row.valueMap}" var="r">

      <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{r}" />
      </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
  </rich:dataTable> 
</h:form>
...
```

Unfortunately, the table doesn't appear. What's wrong? The page doesn't show an error or something, the table is just not there (in this version I skipped all the getter and setter...). When I want to access other data from the bean, it works, so the whole setup should be ok.

Comment: A very similar quesiton has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083444/using-foreach-into-jsf-xhtml

Answer (score 2):

you should not write the "get" and  the "()" in  "getData()",
also, I dont think you need the "foreach" in a datatable

look at this example from 
http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=tableStyling&skin=blueSky

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{carsBean.allInventoryItems}" var="car"
        id="table" rows="20" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
        styleClass="stable">
        <rich:column accept="#{carsFiteringBean.acceptVendor}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Vendor " />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.vendor}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Model" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Price" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.price}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column filter="#{carsFilteringBean.mileageFilterImpl}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Mileage" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.mileage}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="VIN " />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.vin}" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I'm not sure if I got it right. As you can see in the above code, "getData()" is a method which returns a List of elements. There is no attribute in the bean called data or something else. I removed the brackets but still not working.

Comment: @inGoogleITrust: EL does not call attributes .. It calls getter/setter methods. I.e. `#{bean.data}` does under the covers exactly the same as `bean.getData()`! Go back to your school books. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info Calling arbitrary methods only works since EL 2.2. So I think you was misled by that. Your concrete problem boils down to using `<c:forEach>` inside `<rich:dataTable>` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value="#{bean.data}"` instead. Remember, you're using E.L and it is assumed that you're referencing a java bean property named `data` through the getter method `getData()`. The data property might not exists but the method named should definitely be named like this.

Also, in order to use the `items="#{row.valueMap}"` idiom, you must have a `getValueMap()` method present in your bean class.

Do you get the idea?

Comment: yeah that's interesting now, because the following works pretty well (for which there is also no property in the bean)

    <c:forEach items="#{bean.getRecordClassesList()}" var="class">
            <rich:column>
              <h:outputText value="#{class.opClass}" />
            </rich:column>
          
        </c:forEach>

where getRecordClassesList() is a method in the Bean class. The only difference is that in this case, the method is called in the foreach and not in the <datatable>